# OpenGL glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl

Given a set of Faces with each face containing the number of vertices and a pointer to a vertex in a vector std::Vector, i want to iterate over all faces and use glDrawElements to draw each face:

Edit: I just noticed i forgot to activate the vertex_array

```
for(std::vector<Face>::iterator it = faces.begin();it != faces.end();++it) {
    const Face &f = *it;

    std::Vector<GLint> indices;
    std::Vector<GLfloat> positions;

    for(int i=0;i<f.vcount;++i){
        const Vertex &v = vertices[f.vertices[i]];

        positions.push_back(v.x);
        positions.push_back(v.y);
        positions.push_back(v.z);

        indices.push_back(f.vertices[i]);
    }
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,3*sizeof(GL_FLOAT),&positions[0]);                     

    glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON,indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&indices[0]);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    positions.clear();
    indices.clear();
}
```

But apparently this does not work correctly and there is nothing displayed.

Edit: Enabling the GL_VERTEX_ARRAY draws something on the screen but not the model i tried to create. So there seems to be something wrong with the addressing.

Comment: `glVertexPointer` should have `GL_FLOAT` instead of `GL_INT` as second argument, and `3 * sizeof(GLfloat)` as third argument.

Comment: Also, `GL_POLYGON` is not a valid drawing mode anymore. From the documentation: "Symbolic constants GL_POINTS, GL_LINE_STRIP, GL_LINE_LOOP, GL_LINES, GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY, GL_LINES_ADJACENCY, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, GL_TRIANGLES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP_ADJACENCY, GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY and GL_PATCHES are accepted."

Comment: @poetryofruins: "*Also, GL_POLYGON is not a valid drawing mode anymore*" By that reasoning, `glVertexPointer` is also not available anymore in core profile OpenGL. So if he can use one, he can clearly use the other.

Comment: I made the suggested changes but there is still nothing to be seen.

Comment: Are you sure that your indices are correct? If they aren't coming in order from source data you have vertices in completely different positions than indices point to. Also you might be duplicating vertex data if (extremely likely) vertices is referenced multiple times in source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index array doesn't make sense. The indices `glDrawElements` will use just refer to the vertex arrays you have set up - and you are setting up a new array for each separate polygon.

This means that

```
indices.push_back(f.vertices[i]);
```

should be conceptually just

```
indices.push_back(i);
```

which in the end means that you could skip the indices completely and just use

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON,0,f.vcount);
```

Note that what you are doing here is a very inefficent way to render the ojects. You would be much better if you would use a single draw call for the whole object. You could do that by manually triangulating the polygons into triangles as a pre-processing step.

Comment: That worked. But how would i go about using an index. Should the vertex array persist each loop and the index array then point to the start of each polygon?

Comment: That depends. In the simplest form, you would just build one vertex array for the whole object, and no indices at all - you already dereference the indices when building the array, like you do before. This would mean that you move the array itself and the draw call from the inner to the outer loop, and the inner loop would unpack each polygon. A better approach would be to just pack all the distinct vertices into an array, and build an index array which will contain the triangulation for each polygon.